# Within an asp.net application loading several instances of the same page within a session loads synchronously rather than async.

Tags: asp.net, session, asynchronous, multiple-browsers

I have an asp.net application using the .net 3.5 framework, Telerik, and am testing it using IE8.

I have recently received a requirement to allow any of the pages within the application to be loaded on multiple browsers for the same session.

We are using session to persist some of the data across page loads.

It appears that when the same page is loaded by two or more browsers within the same session, the pages load synchronsly, rather than in parellel.  I added logging within the page_load event of the page.  The logging inidicates that only one page at a time is loads.  Once the page_load for one browser completes there is one to two second delay, then the next browser's page_load fires until all queued pages within the session complete.

My initial thought was that this was a blocking issue.  I have reviewed the code within the asp.net page, and the code referenced by the page for static instances which might cause blocking across multiple pages, and have not found any.

Any ideas on what might be causing the synchonus page_load firing behavior as described above?  Could it potentially be an IE8 issue, or some type of blocking involving session?

Thank you.